# Multiple positions of an array

Tags: javascript

How can I reference more then one position of an array?
Something like this

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
$("form")[0, 2].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using jQuery, you can do this all in a selector.

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
   $("form:eq(0), form:eq(2)").reset();
});
```

EDIT: Using `filter` to do this would be better (thanks @Gumbo):

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
   $("form").filter(":eq(0),:eq(2)").reset();
});
```

Comment: `$("form").filter(":eq(0),:eq(2)")` would be better.

Comment: What about: `form:lt(2)`, or even better (because `:eq` and `:lt` are not native selectors): `$('form').splice(0,2)`.

Comment: @RobW: `form:lt(2)` gets 0 and 1, where as `:eq(0),:eq(2)` gets 0 and 2.  The problem with `splice` is the returned object is not a jQuery object (it's an array).

Comment: @Rocket I see, didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

A multi-dimensional JavaScript array would be referenced like myArray[i][j] (e.g. myArray[0][2]). Your code example doesn't seem to make sense though.

Comment: I'm trying to reset the first and and third forms only.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just do this:

```
$("form")[0].reset();
$("form")[2].reset();
```

or, a little more efficiently:

```
var forms = $("form");
forms[0].reset();
forms[2].reset();
```

A nicer way would be to put a common class "myClass" on each of those two forms and do it like this:

```
$("form.myClass").each(function() {this.reset();});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about saving your selector to a variable and then looping about indizes?

```
var form = $('form');
[1, 2].each(function(value, index) {
    form[value].reset();
});
```